# Sending html email in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I am sending a template html in codeigniter and in fact my email is working perfectly fine.

My problem is how i send a template of html to the email. I got an error because of the variables passed to.

```
public function send_email_accountability($C11, $C4, $C8,$C12)
{
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
    $message = $this->load->view('sample_html',$data,TRUE); 
    $this->load->library('email');
    $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
    $this->email->from('noreply@email.com', 'EMAIL');
    $this->email->to($C11); 
    $this->email->subject('Accountability for'. $C12);
    $this->email->message($message);
}
```

I receive the email but inside the email is php error because the `$data` cannot be passed to. I looked at other stackoverflow problems and it didn't help my problem.

Comment: I could be wrong (hence comment, not answer) but if the content of the message is an error, then you have an error in your view.  Load a test page on the web with your view.  (I don't see $data in the function variables list...perhaps this is the issue?)

Comment: THe function doesn't seems to accept any argument named `$data`. but you are using it here `$message = $this->load->view('sample_html',$data,TRUE);`

Comment: i tried this http://esbueno.noahstokes.com/post/217282039/codeigniter-separate-views-for-clean-html-emails and it didn't work for me properly.

Comment: Where is `$data` defined in your function?

Answer (score 2):

```
public function send_email_accountability($C11, $C4, $C8,$C12)
{
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
    $this->load->library('email');
    $data['title']='HELLO WORLD';
    $this->email->from('noreply@email.com', 'EMAIL');
    $this->email->to($C11); 
    $this->email->subject('Accountability for'. $C12);
    $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
    $msg = $this->load->view('sample_html',$data,TRUE);
    $this->email->message($msg);
    $this->email->send();
}


Try this one
```

Comment: in my html file. i have there a logo image for my email. is the logo included when i send the email?

Answer (score 0):

you are using a data array ($data) to the view, but no values is assigned to it,
just assign any value to array to avoid the error,

```
$data['logo_img'] = 'images/logo.png';     // add this line before loading the view
```

This logo image is located as $logo_img in the view **sample_html**...

Comment: in my html file. i have there a logo image for my email. is the logo included when i send the email?

Answer (score 0):

use **PHPmailer**. It will help You. I also use it. You can get all information about PHPmailer from [here](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=exampledb)